# Prove that $n\varphi(m)=m \varphi(n)$

Tags: integers

If the same prime that divides $m$ and $n$, Prove that $n\varphi(m)=m \varphi(n)$

Then what is the relation between $m$ and $n$
Is it $m=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}\cdot 2^k$
And $n=p_1^{b_1}\cdots p_n^{b_n}$ ??

If yes what is the next step?
any idea is highly appreciated

Comment: "If the same prime that divides $m$ and $n$".   What do you mean?

Comment: If $m=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}\cdot 2^k$ and $n=p_1^{b_1}\cdots p_n^{b_n}$ then they do not have the same prime factors, do they?  $2|m$ but $2 \not \mid m$.

Comment: **Exact duplicate** of  [Why is $f(x) = x\phi(x)$ injective, i.e. $x\phi(x) = y\phi(y)\Rightarrow x = y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68120/why-is-fx-x-phix-injective-i-e-x-phix-y-phiy-rightarrow-x-y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m$ and $n$ have the same prime factors, $p_1, ....... , p_k$ then

$m = \prod p_i^{a_i}$ for some set of positive integers $a_1, .... , a_k$ and $n = \prod p_i^{b_i}$ for some set of positive integers $b_1,...., b_k$.

The $\phi(m) = \prod (p_i - 1) \prod p_i^{a-1}$ and $\phi(n) = \prod (p_i - 1) \prod p_i^{b_i-1}$.

And $n\phi(m) = \prod p_i^{b_i}\prod (p_i - 1) \prod p_i^{a_i-1}=\prod (p_i - 1)\prod p_i^{a_i+b_i-1}$  and $m\phi(n) = \prod p_i^{a_i}\prod (p_i - 1) \prod p_i^{b_i-1}=\prod (p_i - 1)\prod p_i^{a_i+b_i-1}$.

So $m\phi(n) = n\phi(m)$

But notice that this  may or may not be an if and only if statement.

You've only been asked to prove one direction.

Comment: Your counterexample compares values of $\phi(k)$, not $\phi(k)/k$.

Comment: Oh... how foolish of me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The result you're trying to prove can be rearranged as $\frac{\varphi(m)}{m}=\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$, i.e. $\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P},\,p|m}(1-p^{-1})=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P},\,p|n}(1-p^{-1})$. This is true if precisely the same primes divide $m,\,n$, but not necessarily just because they have one common prime factor. So we see that the $2^k$ factor you suggest is either wrong if none of the $p_i$ are $2$, or unnecessary if one of the $p_i$ is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $n=p_1^{a_1}\dots p_k^{a_k}$ then $\phi(n)=n(\frac{p_1-1}{p_1})\dots(\frac{p_k-1}{p_k})$

Then $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=(\frac{p_1-1}{p_1})\dots(\frac{p_k-1}{p_k})=\frac{\phi(m)}{m}$ as the same primes appear in the prime factorisation of $m$ and $n$

Comment: Then is $m=p_1^(b_1).....p_n^(b_n)?

Comment: Well, I assumed that this is what the first line of the question means. Otherwise it is not true.